# The integral of $\sin^2 x \csc x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am a high school student in year 8 who is just curious about mathematics. I am struggling with mainly the csc x part. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Isn't $$\sin^2x \csc x=\sin x\,?\;\text{And thus its primitive function is}\;\;-\cos x\ldots$$ Of course, whenever the cosecant is defined.

Comment: $\csc x=\frac{1}{\sin x}$... So you may do cancellation when $x\neq k\pi$, where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: and after canceling $cscx$ integral of $sinx$ is $-cosx+c$

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin^2 x \csc x = \sin x$$
$$\int \sin^2 x \csc x =\int \sin x = -\cos x  + C$$

Comment: Perhaps add that $\sin^2 x \csc x$ is undefined at certain points, so the $C$ is perhaps a different constant in different intervals where $\sin^2 x \csc x$ is defined.